# SQL Server Agent Job executed but the log date show future time

Tags: ssis, sql-server-agent, sql-server-job

I have a SQL Server(2014) Job scheduled run at "AM 11:00" on everyday.

I saw the job's log at "2020/01/08 AM 11:40", the Windows server's clock tool displayed right.

But I find out the job's last record executed at "2020/01/08 **PM 06:12**",

I have no idea what happened, does anyone had same problem and know the answer?

Comment: Sharing some screen shots would help. In SSMS, right click on the job, View History and post the images.

Comment: Sorry, this issue reported from my customer, I'm not sure if it is appropriate to post screenshot here.

Comment: You can share screenshots of times the job runs, because what you are describing doesn't make sense. The job history will show exact date/times as well as who ran the job. Perhaps someone else ran the job? Where are you getting the "job's last record"?